# How to make spring custom validator use error messages from .properties file

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Spring Boot Web App.
I have `ValidationMessages.properties` file that contains validation error messages.

Currently, I am using standard JSR-303/JSR-349 Bean Validation (@Size, etc.), everything is configured properly and validation messages from my `ValidationMessages.properties` file are shown.

But I want to add custom validator as well. Here it is :

```
@Component
public class MyCustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyObject.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "someProperty", "some.error.code", "This is a default message for this error !");

    }
}
```

**How can I make this validator to use error messages from `ValidationMessages.properties` file** instead of default message?

e.g. if I have `some.err.msg=This is error` in that file and want its value to be used in that validator and shown, when validation fails.

Comment: You're using `some.error.*code*` in your example code, but then follow up with `some.err.*msg*=This is error` in `ValidationMessages.properties`.

Comment: @Nate ok, I have `some.err.msg` in `.properties` and `some.err.msg` in `rejectIfEmpty...` and it fails with `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'some.err.msg.myObject.someProperty' for locale 'en_US'.`

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649353/springboot-error-message-interpolation-not-working-for-custom-validator)