# Springboot error message interpolation not working for custom validator

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, bean-validation

I mixed both [org.springframework.validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) together with JSR-303 annotation.

JSR-303 annotation:

```
    public class Model{

        private String type;

        private State state;

        @NotNull(message = "{comment.notnull}")
        private String comment;
    }
```

Spring framework validation:

```
@Component
public class ModelValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Model.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        Model model = (Model) obj;

        if (eventModel.getState() == null) {
            errors.reject("state", "error.state.invalidState");
        }
    }
}
```

My `ValidationMessages_en.properties`

```
error.state.invalidState=Invalid state.
comment.notnull=Comment not null.
```

Then my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("ValidationMessages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

When i run my springboot application, the interpolation works for JSR-303, but not the custom validator, did i miss something? Tried for long time but can't figure out.

Result:

```
"error_messages": [
    {
        "error_message": "Comment not null"
    },
    {
        "error_message": "error.state.invalidState"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is any easy way but eventually I had to do like this ,

Added below component ,

```
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Messages {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
    accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    public String get(String property) {
    return accessor.getMessage(property);
    }

}
```

Then I would inject this component in my validator & use above `get("error.state.invalidState")`  method of this class instead of `error.state.invalidState`  directly.

`messageSource` is the bean that you already defined in system. Locale can be externalized and default locale can be set with another configuration.

`MessageSourceAccessor` has lots of overloaded methods, you can directly expose that too if wish to provide those options.

Comment: Yup, your method actually works, i will wait for awhile to see if there is any better answer, if not, i will accept yours. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused between two methods:

[`reject(String errorCode, String defaultMessage)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#reject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

[`rejectValue(String field, String errorCode)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

As your configuration seems fine, just doing the following should solve your problem:

```
errors.rejectValue("state", "error.state.invalidState");
```

Or

```
errors.reject("error.state.invalidState", "Some default message to fallback!");
```